# Memory Error while plotting using matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Trying to plot pandas Dataframe using matplotlib. but it complains about memory error. Need help in resolving the issue.

size of Dataframe: [1835 rows x 1 columns]
Numpy array of same size.

Code is similar to below.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sorted_values = data['values'].sort_values()   # data['values'] is of size 1835 rows x 1 columns
forc = np.array(range(1835), float)
plt.plot(sorted_values, forc, marker='o', ms=3.0, lw=1.5)
```

but matplotlib complain about memory.

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 339, in __call__
return printer(obj)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 228, in <lambda>
png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 119, in print_figure
fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2151, in print_figure
self.figure.dpi = dpi

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 410, in _set_dpi
self.dpi_scale_trans.clear().scale(dpi, dpi)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 1885, in clear
self.invalidate()

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 136, in invalidate
return self._invalidate_internal(value, invalidating_node=self)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 158, in _invalidate_internal
for parent in list(six.itervalues(self._parents)):

MemoryError
```

Comment: That traceback doesn't seem to be related to the code you posted above. It looks as though you are running out of memory when saving the figure as a .png image. You should try reducing the figure canvas size and/or decreasing the DPI.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve myself  by just removing marker (and markersize) while plotting.

Basically, avoid marker while plotting larger data.